# An example for Loeve's extension theorem on independence.

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I have the following theorem from Loeve's book on probability:

> Extension theorem: Minimal $\sigma$-fields over independent classes
>   $C_{t}$ closed under finite intersections are  independent.

I'd like to find an example that shows the need for the condition "closed under finite intersections"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample can be found in "A basic course in probability theory" by Bhattacharya and Waymire. It goes as follows:

> The simple example in which $Ω = \{a, b, c, d\}$ consists of four
>   equally probable outcomes and $C_{1} = \{\{a, b\}\}, C_{2} = \{\{a,c\}, \{a,d\}\}$,
>   shows that the π-system requirement is indispensable.

Where a π-system is a family of subsets closed for finite intersections. We can easily see that the generated $\sigma$-algebras are:

$\sigma(C_{1}) = \{\emptyset ,\{c,d\},\{a,d\},\{b,d\},\{b,c\}, \Omega\}$

$\sigma(C_{2}) = \{\emptyset ,\{a,c\},\{a,d\},\{b,d\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\},\{a,b,d\},\{b,c,d\}, \Omega\}$

Taking $\{b,d\}$ from $C_{1}$ and $\{a,b,d\}$ from $C_{2}$ we have

$P(\{b,d\} \cap \{a,b,d\}) = 1/2$ but
$P(\{b,d\})*P(\{a,b,d\}) = 3/8$